# How to change position of labels in Doughnut chart?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, chart.js, legend

I have created one doughnut chart.

```
var ctx=document.getElementById('mycanvas').getContext('2d');
            var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: {
            labels: ["CL", "ML", "Spl.L", "PD","Other Permissions"],
            datasets: [{
            label: "My First dataset",
            backgroundColor: [' #F0CB8C','#EE97A1','#A9D5D4','#E8A3D7','#CFA3FD'],          
            data: [ 7, 3, 3],
            }]
            },
            options: {
              tooltips: { bodyFontSize: 25 }
            }
            });
```

Here I want to show the labels right side of the chart in a vertical position.
How to do it?

Complete code:https://jsfiddle.net/axoy2Ljt/

Comment: Did you try to using [legend position](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#position) .   `Chart.defaults.global.legend.position ='right;'`

Comment: @agit I thave tried by adding like this options: {
    tooltips: { bodyFontSize: 25 },
    legend:{
     display:'right'
    }
    
   }, its not working.

Comment: does this work for you ? : [https://jsfiddle.net/30ngcpsz/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/30ngcpsz/1/)

Comment: @agit thanks man.but I couldn't get expected result :-(:-( check my updated image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get your expected result ...

**ꜰɪʀꜱᴛ**

set **`position: 'right'`** for `legend` in your chart options :

```
options: {
   legend: {
      position: 'right'
   }
}
```

**ꜱᴇᴄᴏɴᴅ**

wrap the canvas with a div element *(`.chart-container`)* and set it­*'s* width and height, instead of setting it for the canvas element itself :

```
.chart-container {
   width: 280px;
   height: 280px;
}
```

also, you should use the latest version of Chart.js, which is `2.7.1` atm.

Here is a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/xm80qzoo/).

Comment: one more help.Can you please tell me how to change the size of label boxes ;-) ;-0

Comment: set the `boxWidth` property accordingly for labels.. see - https://jsfiddle.net/xm80qzoo/1/

Comment: This is outdated as of 3.6.0 (and probably before) see my answer below

Answer (score 5):

The latest version of chart.js has slightly different syntax and needs to be wrapped in `plugins`

```
options: {
   plugins: {
      legend: {
         position: 'right'
      }
   }
}
```